# MySQL: Optimizing a 300+ second query?

Tags: mysql

I have a classiffieds website and we got A LOT of new visitors this month.

The website simply exploded and started to deliver a "Can't connect with DB". I'm using codeigniter and this is the trace un Mysql Logs:

```
# Time: 160924 22:50:20
# Thread_id: 1914  Schema: erich33_asd  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 378.515875  Lock_time: 375.061742  Rows_sent: 75  Rows_examined: 152644
SET timestamp=1474771820;
SELECT `category`.`id` as `category_id`, `category`.`subcat` as `category_name`, `category`.`desc` as `category_desc`, `category`.`name` as `category_pretty_name`, `ads`.`id`, `ads`.`header`, `ads`.`price`, SUBSTR(ads.body, 1, 160) as body, `ads`.`sellfast`, `ads`.`foto1`, `ads`.`foto2`, `ads`.`foto3`, `ads`.`foto4`, `ads`.`foto5`, `ads`.`updated`, `ads`.`created`, `ads`.`hits`, `promo`.`promotype` as `promo_type`, `provinces`.`prov_name`, `supercategory`.`name` as `supercategory_name`, `supercategory`.`id` as `supercategory_id`
FROM `ads`
JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id` = `ads`.`subcat_id`
JOIN `supercategory` ON `supercategory`.`id` = `category`.`cat`
JOIN `provinces` ON `provinces`.`id` = `ads`.`province_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `promo` ON `promo`.`ads_id` = `ads`.`id`
WHERE `ads`.`subcat_id` = '22'
AND `recycle_bin` != 1
AND `hidden` =0
ORDER BY `promo_type` DESC, `updated` DESC
LIMIT 833, 75;
```

As you can see it took **378.515875 seconds** to complete.

How would you optimize this query to take less time?

Comment: You need to use MySQL's EXPLAIN verb to run the query analyser and tell you what the query will do.  It will depend in things like what indexes you have defined in your schema.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a bad index configuration in DB schema.
Just added an index in ads.recycle_bin, ads.hidden and ads.subcat_id

Thanks!